# Python reshaping for the transpose is returning an error of different dimensions when dot product is used

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I need to calculate the weights of linear regression model using the expression below:

[image]

We should use reshape in order to get the transpose of X having the shape of (100, 3).

I used:

```
xT = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

then, I wanted to get the dot of X transpose with X:

```
xDot = np.dot(Xtrain, xT)
```

And I got the following error:

> shapes (100,3) and (300,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 300 (dim 0)

How the reshape should be in that case?

Comment: You probably want `x.T` not `x.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: In `dot(A,B)` the last of A matches the 2nd to the last of B.  If `Xtrain` is (100,3), `xT` must be (3,n) (it can also be (3,)).

Comment: @hpaulj how to fix that?

Comment: @mozway would it work with .T

Comment: Have you tried? ;)

Comment: @mozway it worked as follows: `w = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(Xtrain), Ytrain)` without the need to transpose, I think it's because of the `pinv` instead of the `inv` function.